# Terminate Async Call

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have the following code, where `async` operation executes. The following code works, but my question is how to cancel/terminate `async` operation?

In other words, while app is working in the background by calling `[self addAllImages]` and then user navigates to other view, and I should terminate this `async` call.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
      [self addAllImages];
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            [self pageControlSetUp];
            self.fullScreenImageView.hidden = YES;
        });
});
```

Comment: Please do a [little searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+cancel+dispatch_async) before posting.

Comment: @rmaddy, I did. It says to use `cancellAllOperation`, but it does not apply here.

Comment: Click the link I put in my comment. The search results are for `dispatch_async`.